# How to fix "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" with multiple databases in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to configure multiple datasources with spring boot, postgres will be my primary db and oracle will be the secondary one. I have my configuration as given the code. Whenever I am trying to make the application up I am getting the following error.

```
2019-05-16 23:30:37.864  INFO 27873 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
2019-05-16 23:30:37.865  INFO 27873 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-05-16 23:30:37.889  INFO 27873 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-05-16 23:30:40.396  INFO 27873 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2019-05-16 23:30:42.705  INFO 27873 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@55e1192
2019-05-16 23:32:46.882  WARN 27873 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
2019-05-16 23:32:46.882 ERROR 27873 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

2019-05-16 23:32:47.102  WARN 27873 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oracleEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/hdfc/sync/OracleDbConfiguration2.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2019-05-16 23:32:47.107  INFO 27873 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-05-16 23:32:47.129  INFO 27873 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-16 23:32:47.140 ERROR 27873 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oracleEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/hdfc/sync/OracleDbConfiguration2.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.hdfc.sync.SyncApplication.main(SyncApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:213) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:37) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:733) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1276) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:366) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Here is the code for the same.

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
    exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SyncApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SyncApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:oracle-db.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.hdfc.sync.oracle.repo",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "oracleEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "oracleTransactionManager")
public class OracleDbConfiguration2 {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
        = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(oracleDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.hdfc.sync.oracle.domain"});
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource oracleDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.jdbcUrl"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean(name = "oracleTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager oracleTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(oracleEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:postgres-db.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.hdfc.sync.postgresql.repo",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "postgresTransactionManager")
public class PostgresDbConfiguration2 {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgresEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(postgresDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.hdfc.sync.postgresql.domain" });
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("postgresql.datasource.jdbcUrl"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("postgresql.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("postgresql.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager postgresTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(postgresEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
hibernate.connection.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.connection.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Removed the url, username and password from properties just for the question.

The packages for domain entity and repositories are empty time being.

When I am configuring them separately(one at a time) using the same code , it works, but together it doesn't work.

For oracle jdbc driver I have included only 1 jar i.e:ojdbc8.jar

Answer (score 0):

try using @qualifier oracle datasource configuration and in class where you are autowiring this oracle instance.